# Binary bomb phase 2 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, reverse-engineering

I am working on phase 2 of binary bomb assignment. On line `<+54>` the program compares the values of the content of `%eax` register and memory location `(%rsp + 4*%rbx)`. Both values equal 5; however, the program does not jump to line `<+38>`, it goes to the `<explode_bomb>` function instead. What am I doing wrong? As an input for this phase I entered 4 1 2 3 5 6.

[image: <code>disas</code> output]

[image: Compared values]

Comment: Can you stop at the `je` instead, and also `p $eflags`? Also do `x/wd $rsp+$rbx*4` to avoid possible pointer scaling issues.

Comment: (gdb) p $eflags
$1 = [ CF PF AF SF IF ]
(gdb) x/wd $rsp+$rbx*4
0x7fffffffd6e4: 1

Comment: See, that is the problem. I assume casting to `(int*)` activated the C pointer scaling. Assembly uses byte addressing, that is the actual reason for the `*4` being in the instruction. So you were just looking at a different place than what the instruction is accessing.

Comment: If you don't like the `x` you can probably put the cast last, e.g. `p *(int*)($rsp+$rbx*4)`. Or you could drop the `*4` and do `p *((int*)$rsp+$rbx)`.